# Having trouble setting up my pom.xml correctly to pass a variable to an XML file

Tags: java, xml, maven, build

So I'm fumbling my way through this, it's a project that I'm taking the reigns of because nobody else can (original dev left, nobody else with any experience to do it) but I'm trying my hardest here. My apologies if what I have already makes no sense, I'm not a developer really.

So I have my pom.xml file, and in the resources section I have it pulling values from some resource directories, depending on the profile used:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources/${profile.name}</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>../../webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</include>
        </includes>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

One line in src/main/resources/test/application.properties is the following:

```
app.api.databaseUrl=jdbc:mysql://databasehostname:3306/testDatabase
```

You'll notice up above that I tried getting it to place this value in my applicationContext.xml file, so that a different database can be used for test and prod profiles - but that piece isn't working. It seems to be pulling all the values from application.properties, but I can't figure out how to put those in applicationContext.xml. Here's what I have in that file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="${app.api.databaseUrl}"/>
    <property name="username" value="username" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>

<bean id="cartDAO" class="com.crown.apps.cart.dao.impl.CartDAOImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

When building the war file, "${app.api.databaseUrl}" does not change to the correct value, it stays the same.

I'm sure I'm doing something completely and utterly wrong, I'm sure my pom.xml setup is wrong but I don't know where to begin fixing it. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using Spring 3.x, so please check [this article](http://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring#xml). Basically, you have to specify the location of properties file in your beans configuration XML: `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:foo.properties" />`